# Drivers to screen, audio, keyboard/mouse

Tags: drivers, nvidia, screen, ati

I am new to ubuntu, and I am about to replace Windows 7 with Ubuntu 11.10. I know how to install the operating system from a CD. But when I have done that, do I need to install any drivers? for Screen, sound, keybord/mouse, internet etc?

Computer specs: HP-Pavilion KX664AA-UUW m9354.sc
Graphics Card: NVIDIA GeForce 9500 GT, Processor: AMD Phenom(tm) 8450 Triple-Core Processor. I do not know if these specs are necessary for you, but I put them on anyways

I'm not that good at computers, so it would be fine with an answer that was explained easily. Looking forward to start using Ubuntu instead of Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need to install drivers for the hardware you have listed.  It is possible if you are using a wireless card that you would need to install drivers for it.  Your graphics card is supported by an open source driver that lacks 3D support.  To get 3D support, you will have to install the nvidia drivers.  The details can be found in the help pages:  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia